# Insert Spark Dataframe into Hive Table

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a Hive Table existing, stored as orc, that has the same schema as the data frame I create with my spark job.  If I save the data frame down as css, json, text, whatever then it works just fine.  I can hand migrate these files into a Hive table just fine.

but when I try and insert directly into hive with

```
df.insertInto("table_name", true)
```

I get this error in the YARN UI:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'cast(last_name_2 as array<double>)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StringType to ArrayType(DoubleType,true);
```

I've also tried register a temp table before calling insert and also using:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("default.table_name")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the schema of the dataframe compared to the Hive table?

Comment: they are identical.  I actually used a df.printSchema() in the shell with this code to determine the schema...that's why this is so odd to me.  I'm certainly not trying to cast `last_name_2` as an array of doubles, though I do have `array<double>` in the schema of both, just a different field.

Comment: Someone told me that order matters to Hive.  Is this true?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The columns are definitely ordered.

Comment: Column order matters. If the dataframe and hive table have the same columns but in different orders you will get this error.

Comment: Tim, yes, I found out column order matters a while back.